RS232 to USB Exception throwing Device connected is not functioning properly and cannot close the port
I am hitting an issue where I am using RS232 to USB and trying to communicate to a device using SCPI. It is throwing IO exception "The device attached is not functioning properly" and afterwards I cannot close the port. Has any one hit something similar? System.IO.IOException: A device attached to the system is not functioning C# .NET 4.0
Tried debugging and root causing but not working.
